# Still get firebase measurementId warning after relink to firebase analytics

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-analytics

I just tried to relink the project to firebase analytics. After that, the measurementId changed. I added new measurementId to HTML and deployed it. But, I still get a warning "*The measurement ID in the local Firebase config (G-SWHXV050SE) does not match the measurement ID fetched from the server (G-9XKSB1V3PD)*" and an error "*GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?l=dataLayer&id=G-9XKSB1V3PD net::ERR_ABORTED 404*"

Here is my code

```
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-database.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script>
      // NOTE - INCLUDE YOUR FIREBASE CONFIG HERE FOR ANYTHING TO WORK:
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyDlJX8Aub35ObEgDcV-zk064gnKu69jI9U",
        authDomain: "dogbox-multiplayer.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://dogbox-multiplayer-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "dogbox-multiplayer",
        storageBucket: "dogbox-multiplayer.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "321715391463",
        appId: "1:321715391463:web:14d4179d27e869d06c0b42",
        measurementId: "G-SWHXV050SE"
      };
      const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const analytics = firebase.analytics(app);
    </script>
```

I also tried adding

```
<!-- Google tag (gtag.js) -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-SWHXV050SE"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'G-SWHXV050SE');
</script>
```

The error changed to "*GET https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-9XKSB1V3PD&l=dataLayer&cx=c net::ERR_ABORTED 404*" and the warning is still the same.

Comment: Why do you attempt to use firebase on web? Firebase analytics only makes sense for apps. For web, you're supposed to use GA4 through GTM (preferably) or gtag.js

Comment: It's the only thing I had used before. I'm quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is not made for reporting. Despite having impressive data framework, it's a poor reporting tool only viable for debugging. Let's just say Firebase is only good for native app tracking.

I'll give you a top-level walkthrough to properly install GA4 for web, but I won't go into details too much since it would've been a large article instead.

0. Remove libs you've installed so far. Whether it's analytics.js, gtag.js or firebase. Remove the datalayer declaration too, unless you know how to use it.
1. Register a GA4 property (if you don't have one) and set it up to your best ability. While doing so, make a source for web traffic and copy its measurement id.
2. Register a GTM container for web, not server-side (if you don't have one), copy its installation code and add it to your html source as GTM suggests. Feel free to ignore the   part. GTM likes to pretend it doesn't need JS.
3. In GTM, make a GA4 pageview tag, set the measurement id that you copied from GA4 in that tag, bind it to a new pageview trigger.
4. Publish the container to production. Don't preview it without publishing. If a container hasn't ever been published, it will keep returning a 404. Because Google doesn't really care enough to make an automatic empty publish on container creation.
5. Let's test it properly now: install [chrome extension from adswerve](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom), enable it, go to your site and reload a page. Open the console. You'll see the extension logging tracking into the console.
6. Now go to your GA4 property, check real time data, make sure you see your hits. And other people's hits too, since you've published it.

This concludes it. Using GTM for web-tracking is the best practice for an average site.